# Waiting time calculation for taxi hailing application

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing a taxi hailing application using react native. I want to calculate the waiting time of the vehicle so that it could be added to the calculation of the final fare. What is the best method to calculate this?

Currently, I tried to access the speed attribute in the navigator geolocation library available in react native. But that approach did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [watchPosition](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation#watchposition)()  and match with the coordinates / location of the customer (consider at least 30 meters radius). Once matches start the timer `until` customer reaches the vehicle or journey has started. Don't forget to call `stopObserving()` at last